# HTACCESS RewriteRule not working on all redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-302

I was updating a website today and to my surprise, one of my new RewriteRules do not work. I am using the same "syntax" on all the rules but still problem.

My code is:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^produktinformation-om-(.*)/?$ /produktinformation.php?product=$1

RewriteRule ^nyhet-(.*)-(.*)/?$ /merinfonyhet.php?id=$2


RewriteRule (sv|en|cn)/$ /actions/action.set.language.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule (sv|en|cn)/(.+)/$ /actions/action.goto.page.php?lang=$1&page=$2



## MENU START

RewriteRule ^information/?$ /information.php
RewriteRule ^kontakt/?$ /kontakt.php
RewriteRule ^nyheter/?$ /nyheter.php
RewriteRule ^kvalitet/?$ /kvalitet.php

RewriteRule ^produkter/?$     /produkter.php
RewriteRule ^antioxidanter/?$    /category.php?cat=0 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vitaminer/?$     /category.php?cat=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^mineraler/?$     /category.php?cat=2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^viktkontroll/?$    /category.php?cat=3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^leder-muskler/?$    /category.php?cat=4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^omega-3/?$     /category.php?cat=5 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^smart-mat/?$     /category.php?cat=6 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^syn-tanke/?$     /category.php?cat=7 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kraft-energi-fokus/?$   /category.php?cat=8 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hjartat-karl/?$    /category.php?cat=9 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^nedstamndhet-stress/?$  /category.php?cat=10 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^samlevnad-lust-potens/?$  /category.php?cat=11 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^resa/?$      /category.php?cat=12 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^laktosintolerans/?$   /category.php?cat=13 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hud-o-naglar/?$    /category.php?cat=14 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^halsokost/?$     /category.php?cat=15 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^halsomat/?$     /category.php?cat=16 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^barnmat/?$     /category.php?cat=17 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pannkakor/?$     /category.php?cat=18 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vafflor/?$     /category.php?cat=19 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vlcdFrukost/?$    /category.php?cat=20 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vlcdSoppor/?$     /category.php?cat=21 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^vlcdShakesDrycker/?$   /category.php?cat=22 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^fettforbranning/?$   /category.php?cat=23 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kolhydratsblockerare/?$  /category.php?cat=24 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^grot/?$      /category.php?cat=25 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^modersmjolksersattning/?$  /category.php?cat=26 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^valling/?$     /category.php?cat=27 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^omega3-junior/?$    /category.php?cat=28 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^stillavatten/?$    /category.php?cat=29 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^lattkolsyrat/?$    /category.php?cat=30 [NC,L]
## MENU END
```

The problem I get is with "**RewriteRule ^stillavatten/?$           /category.php?cat=29 [NC,L]**" Third from bottom in the code.

If I write for example: **`http://www.thepage.com/stillavatten/`** , then I will get a **302 response** with a blank page.

If I take away the "**/**" at the end, I will get to the right page.

If I try the same on any of the other rewrites, it works with or without the "**/**".

I have tried alot of different solutions but no success and it is driving me crazy :) I added "[NC, L]" to every line but that did not help.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you see anything unusual if you show hidden/whitespace characters in your editor? TrIed deleting the entire line and typing it again, manually?

Comment: I have no hidden blank spaces and no weird hidden characters. I remade the whole file line by line and still same problem. I added all the code from my HTACCESS in my original post now.

Answer (score 1):

`GET /stillavatten/` also matches the rule 4 match pattern `(sv|en|cn)/$`.  You forgot to anchor this :)

Comment: Oh..., yea ... hmm... Guess if I feel stupid now :) . A really big thanks for the help TerryE . I was pulling my hair on that one. I added a "^" infront of those 2 lines and it works now.

Comment: Hi I have folder inside my subdomain and I want to rewrite code. Eg: https://sub.newdomain.com this is my subdomain. I have a folder test  inside the subdomain directory. 

" RewriteRule ^/?test/([^/d]+)/?$ test/index.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L] "

This is my htaccess code. But when I try to call https://sub.newdomain.com/test/test it returns 404 error. How Can I fix it. Apache mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: @SoorajlalKG, the regexp `^/?test/([^/d]+)/?$` doesn't do what you think it does. Try a regexp checker to play.